# Does a witness cut a bet?

Tags: phrase-request

In my country, when conditions of a bet (a dare) are sealed, the two parties shake hands. If there's a third, neutral party serving as a witness/judge of the bet/dare, they "cut" it - lower extended hand like a blade (chopping motion) onto the two connected hands, "cutting the bond", breaking the handshake.

How is this act called in English? Is such custom even practised in any anglophone countries?

Comment: I've never come across this practice in the UK, I can't speak for any other anglophone countries though.

Comment: American here, and I've never encountered this in my life.  (Neat!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar expression: [To cut a deal](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+a+deal), though you don't strictly speaking have to shake hands for the expression to work.

We don't have a term for the *exact* act you described because a witness to a deal doesn't place their hand on the handshake in English culture.

EDIT: Maybe [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TeamHandStack) is similar to what you described?

Comment: I believe the linked custom is definitely different. I believe the symbolism is "the friendship is severed until the conditions of the bet are satisfied."

Comment: I agree, the meaning is different. I don't believe there's a word or expression in the English language that has the symbolism you described.